Lean 4 error: unknown module prefix
I have a lean project with 2 files (/home/usr345/logics directory):
Classical_2.lean:
namespace Classical_2
...
end Classical_2

Quantifiers_1.lean:
import Classical_2

namespace Quantifiers_1
...
end Quantifiers_1

Unfortunately, when I am running lean Quantifiers_1.lean, I get an error:
./Quantifiers_1.lean:1:0: error: unknown module prefix 'Classical_2'

No directory 'Classical_2' or file 'Classical_2.olean' in the search path entries:
/home/usr345/.elan/toolchains/stable/lib/lean

How to tell lean to search the file Classical_2.lean inside the same directory as Quantifiers_1.lean?
I tried to do the steps from Creating a Lean project from the official documentation:
$ lake new logics
This created a new directory, then copied my 2 files Classical_2.lean and Quantifiers_1.lean into Logics subdirectory. Now it looks like this (hidden files omitted):
├── lakefile.lean
├── lake-manifest.json
├── lean-toolchain
├── Logics
│   ├── Classical_2.lean
│   └── Quantifiers_1.lean
├── Logics.lean
├── Main.lean
└── README.md

But it didn't help: when I run $lean Quantifiers_1.lean I still get the same error. I  don't have VS code and don't want to use it.
Does anybody know, how to launch lean directly for a group of files?

This really isn’t the right way to call Lean from the command line for a multi file project.  Use lake to setup and build the project.  https://leanprover-community.github.io/install/project.html

Also note, the typical way to use lean for checking a proof is via an editor plugin, but there are legitimate usecases for checking from the command line too.

@JasonRute I did the steps from the manual, but it didn't work. Do you know, how to launch it without VS Code?

So, to repeat my comments, typically Lean is checked via VS Code or Emacs.  This makes interactive theorem proving actually interactive.  However if you want, you can check your file from the command line using lean, but if you have multiple interconnected files then you need to set us a Lean project with lake, the Lean project manager.
Setup the Lean project
See Creating a Lean Project for how to setup a new Lean project.  These instructions are mathlib focused, but the main idea is that you type:
lake new my_new_project

You also can add different options to the end (see lake new --help)

std (default): Builds both a library file (Logic.lean in this example) and an executable Main.lean.  The library is for importing into other projects, or just for proofs.  The executable is if you are making a runnable programming application.
lib: Omits Main.lean.
exe: Omits the library file.
math: Omits Main.lean and installs Mathlib as a dependency. (If doing this, then you should run lake exe cache get to avoid compiling all of Mathlib.)

(For coding applications, you can also see the project setup instructions in Functional Programming in Lean 4.)
How to reference files in a project
To reference another Lean file, or even another Lean project, use import.  Using your project structure, it would look like this:
import Logics.Classical_2

Notice, I used the full path, but using . instead of / and I also didn't include .lean.
If you want a starting point for checking all your files, you can put imports for all the files in Logics in Logics.lean like:
import Logics.Classical_2
import Logics.Quantifiers_1

This makes it easy to check/compile your project in one step.  Also, it makes it possible to use this project inside another one.  (You have to modify the lakefile of the other project which imports this one.)  Then you can use import Logics to import all Lean files called from Logics.lean.  Or you can still use specific imports like import Logics.Quantifiers_1.
Finally, note that import Logics.Quantifiers_1 automatically imports all dependencies, including Logits.Classical_2.
Running Lean from the command line in a project
Assuming your project structure, you have two options for running Lean.
lake env lean Logics/Quantifiers_1.lean

will run Lean (including type checking, proof checking, #evals, etc.) on that file, but be aware of the package structure.
Alternately, you can use lake build.  This will build a file and all its dependencies.  Building includes running Lean for type checking and proof checking, but also includes compiling any code, and most importantly turning each Lean file into a compiled .olean file. The files are located in .lake/build/lib/ directory and it's subdirectories. This will avoid having to recheck/recompile dependencies in the future (if they haven't changed).
You can run lake build for a single file with
lake build Logics.Quantifiers_1

Notice this uses the .-style paths.  You can also run
lake build

and I think this builds any file referenced in Logics.lean or Main.lean (and any recursive imports).
